# Can TeamCity run builds if source code on local machine?

Tags: jenkins, teamcity

I've been playing around with Jenkins and found that you can manually place source code into a workspace directory in the .jenkins folder and build projects without a source code management tool. I know this isn't the best practice, but then again I've only been playing around with it.

I tried picking up TeamCity and noticed that TeamCity will ONLY build projects brought in by remote SCM tools (Git, Subversion, etc). Question: Is there a way to import source code that is on my local machine, without the help of SCM, and building it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add a plugin into your ide (eclipse/intellij) and sendin files that are local changes but not yet committed to the repository.

The feature is called Remote run

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Remote+Run